# How to reference related model through composite ID

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

I have created a model in Loopback based off a MySQL view, called "Active UserSessionStats" (referenced below). For this particular view, due to the nature of my application, I can't create a single unique primary key, and instead I have created (I think) a composite key from the "departmentId" and the "userId". I'm able to access this model just fine from the API, but I'd like to associate it with another model, "ActiveUserSessions" (referenced below). However, I'm not sure how to use a composite ID to create the association. My goal would be that I could access an ActiveUserSession, and then include the stats model as necessary.

I'd love some help on either thinking how to create a relationship using a composite ID in Loopback, or another potential approach that I'm not thinking of that could help establish the connection between these two models.

Here are the two models:

```
// active-user-sessions.json
{
  "name": "ActiveUserSessions",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mysql": {
    "schema": "db",
    "table": "active_user_sessions"
  },
  "properties": {
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "created_at",
        "dataType": "datetime",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "default": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 3,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "default",
        "dataType": "tinyint",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 3,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "departmentId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "department_id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "deviceUuid": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false,
      "length": 255,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "device_uuid",
        "dataType": "varchar",
        "dataLength": 255,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "endTime": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "end_time",
        "dataType": "datetime",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "startTime": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "start_time",
        "dataType": "datetime",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "targetEarnedTime": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "target_earned_time",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "targetEndTime": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "target_end_time",
        "dataType": "datetime",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "unallocatedLaborTime": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "unallocated_labor_time",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "updated_at",
        "dataType": "datetime",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "userId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "user_id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "userStateId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "user_state_id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "stats": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "ActiveUserSessionStats",
      "foreignKey": ["userId","departmentId"]  
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}



//active-user-session-stats.json
{
  "name": "ActiveUserSessionStats",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mysql": {
    "schema": "db",
    "table": "active_user_session_stats"
  },
  "properties": {
    "allocatedLaborTime": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 32,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "allocated_labor_time",
        "dataType": "decimal",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 32,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "earnedTime": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 32,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "earned_time",
        "dataType": "decimal",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 32,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "targetEarnedTime": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 32,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "target_earned_time",
        "dataType": "decimal",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 32,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "userId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "id": 1,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "user_id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    },
    "departmentId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "id":2,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "department_id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "Y"
      },
      "_selectable": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "activeUserSession": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "ActiveUserSessions",
      "foreignKey": ["userId","departmentId"]
    }  
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: As a note - I recognize that the foreign keys as defined right now are incorrect - but I did this to represent the type of relationship I'm hoping to establish between the two models.

Comment: Doesn't `ActiveUserSession` `hasOne` `ActiveUserSessionStats` relation suits you ?

Comment: @Overdrivr Yes, ideally, but that's based on the assumption that the `ActiveUserSessionStats` model has a foreign key I can connect with. The challenge is that it doesn't have one, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to make the connection on a composite ID.